# Cordova : how to capture video and then upload to the PHP server (JS + PHP code)

Tags: javascript, php, cordova

There are exemples on the web or on the cordova documentation but not always complete or up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working exemple :

The two button in the HTML file :

```
<a data-role="button" onclick="captureVideo()">Capture video</a>
<a data-role="button" onclick="uploadVideo()">Send me</a>
```

In the JS file :

```
var path = '';

function captureVideo() {
    // capture callback
    var captureSuccess = function(mediaFiles) {
        path = mediaFiles[0].fullPath;
    };

    // capture error callback
    var captureError = function(error) {
        navigator.notification.alert('Error code: ' + error.code, null, 'Capture Error');
    };

    // start video capture
    navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError,  {limit:1});
}

function uploadVideo() {
    var win = function (r) {
        console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
        console.log("Response = " + r.response);
        console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
    }

    var fail = function (error) {
        alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
        console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
        console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
    }

    var fileURL = path;

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = fileURL.substr(fileURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    options.mimeType = "video/mp4";

    var params = {};
    params.value1 = "test";
    params.value2 = "param";

    options.params = params;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(fileURL, encodeURI("https://myserver.com/php/upload.php"), win, fail, options);
}
```

The PHP file upload.php :

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');

$uploaddir = '../video/'; //folder https://myserver.com/video 
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File uploaded\n";
}
else {
    echo "Error\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: This is an Answer to my own question ! This solution works and I wanted to share it

Comment: I put this code here to help other people but someone downvoted without telling why. 
You can find almost identical js code online. But I added the PHP to code so people who want to implemant will have everything